# JSON malformed exception (Android Kotlin Retrofit PHP MySQL)

Tags: php, android, json, kotlin, retrofit

I am developing an app with Kotlin-PHP-MySql.

I will be appreciated if someone has an idea why I get this exception "com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path" when I call *createUser* function.

I don't get an exception when I call *getUser* function with Same api.

I checked these two functions in postman. JSONs are formatted properly. Begins with
`{ "key" : "value", "key1" : "value1", .... }`

This is my api:

```
     interface Api {
     ...
     @POST("/api/v1/users/register_user.php")
     suspend fun createUser(
         @Body userDto: UserInfoPreviewDto
     ) : QueryResponse

     @POST("/api/v1/users/get_user.php")
     suspend fun getUser(
         @Body  jsonObject : JsonObject
     ) : UserDto
    }
```

and my Retrofit instance:

```
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(RamonApiUser::class.java)
```

and my server-side php code is
register_user.php file:

```
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
      header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow- 
            Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
      include_once("../../config/database.php");
      include_once("../../classes/user.php");
      $db = new Database();
      $connection = $db->connect();
      $user = new User($connection);
      if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $user->username =  $data->username;
        $user->password =  $data->password;
        $user->fullname =  $data->fullname;
        $user->email =  $data->email;
        if($user->register()) {
            http_response_code(200);
            $result = array( 
                "status" => "200", 
                "message" => "saved"
            );
            echo json_encode($result);
         }
         else {
            http_response_code(500);
            echo json_encode(array(
                "status" => "500",
                "message" => "Error 500"   
            ));
        }    
      }
      else {
          http_response_code(503);
          echo json_encode(array(
                                 "status" => "503",
                                 "message" => "Error 503"   
                           ));
      }
```

this my get_user.php file:

```
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, 
             Authorization, X-Requested-With");
    include_once("../../config/database.php");
    include_once("../../classes/user.php");
    $db = new Database();
    $connection = $db->connect();
    $user = new User($connection);  
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {
        $param = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        if(!empty($param->id)) {
            $user->id = $param->id;
            $user_data = $user->getById();
            if (!empty($user_data)) {
                http_response_code(200);
                $user_data['isPublicProfile'] = (bool)$user_data['isPublicProfile']; 
                $user_data['isLastOnlineVisible'] = 
                                     (bool)$user_data['isLastOnlineVisible'];
                $user_data['isPhoneNumberVisible'] = 
                                     (bool)$user_data['isPhoneNumberVisible'];
                echo json_encode($user_data);
            }
        } 
     }
     else {
          http_response_code(503);
          echo json_encode(array(
                     "status" => "0",
                     "message" => "503 error"   
       ));
     }
```

getById() function in user.php :

```
    public function getById() {
        $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM ". $this->table_name ." WHERE id = ? LIMIT 0,1";
        $obj = $this->conn->prepare($sqlQuery);
        $obj->bind_param("i", $this->id);
        $obj->execute();
        $data = $obj->get_result();
        return $data->fetch_assoc();
    }
```

I have QueryResponse data class in the client-side with the fields *status* and *message*. `user->register()` returns *true* or *false* . I think the problem is with my json_encode method. I also tried this:
I created a QueryReponse php class with fields *status* and *message* and encode this object like this:

```
    $query_response = new QueryResponse();
    $query_response->status = "200";
    $query_response->message = "registration successful";
    $echo json_encode($query_response);
```

it didn't help either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrofit2.0 gets MalformedJsonException while the json seems correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35984898/retrofit2-0-gets-malformedjsonexception-while-the-json-seems-correct) or [Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39918814/use-jsonreader-setlenienttrue-to-accept-malformed-json-at-line-1-column-1-path)

Comment: @ficuscr Unfortunately no. I think the problem is with the "@Body" in my api. When I don't use "@Body", it doesn't throw any exceptions. Check my answer

Comment: Take a look at this: [Retrofit with kotlin, unable to create @Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675527/retrofit-with-kotlin-unable-to-create-body/45678196) - seems very similar. Sorry to just link things but trying to help how I can.

Comment: @ficuscr
No problem, thanks for your efforts. But I have no problems with my retrofit instance. I have ConverterFactory added. My api works with all other functions, like getUser, getQueryResponse and more. Only in this register_user.php file, it throws exception

Comment: @ficuscr user registration is successful by the way. I forgot to mention that. I just can't return a valid json object after registration completed. which is soo easy. I just need this to work in my register.php file: $result = array( "status" =>"200", "message" => "saved") echo json_encode($result)

Answer (score 0):

I created another file called get_query_response.php. Just to make sure that my QueryResponse classes are OK and doesn't throw exceptions.

get_query_response.php:

```
     ....
     include_once("../../config/database.php");
     include_once("../../classes/query_response.php");
     $db = new Database();
     $connection = $db->connect();
     $query_response = new QueryResponse($connection);
     if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {
            $query_response->id = 1;
            $query_response_data = $query_response->getById();
            // I fetch query_response_data from mysql
            if (!empty($query_response_data)) {
                http_response_code(200);
                $result = array(
                    "status" => "500",
                    "message" => "save successfully"
                );
                echo json_encode($result); // doesn't throw exception. 
                                               works fine
                //echo json_encode($query_response_data); 
                //when i use this line, it doesn't throw exception 
                //either. works fine
            }       
      }
```

I call this file *get_query_response.php* from my api like this:

```
    interface MyApi {
    ...
    @POST("/api/v1/users/get_query_response.php")
    suspend fun getQueryResponse() : QueryResponse
    ...
    }
```

No errors, no exceptions. Both *echo json_encode($result)* and *echo json_encode($query_response_data)* works fine.
The only difference between two register_user.php and get_query_response.php files is this line:

```
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

I don't get the reason why these two files behave differently. They are almost identical. Why does not this code work in register_user.php?

```
            $result = array(
                "status" => "200",
                "message" => "saved successfully"
            );
            echo json_encode($result);
```

I finally solved the problem. It was my data class UserInfo. One field of the class was being assigned null during instantiation. Api is sending a class which two properties of that class has null values. The problem is solved by assigning values to those properties.

Comment: Hi, @rahman. Your answer doesn't look like an actual answer. It looks more like the continuation of the question itself. Might be good to rewrite it if you're able to fix the issue.